download fixed rows using load_dataset()
While loading a huggingface dataset, I want to download only a subset of the full dataset.
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("openslr/librispeech_asr", split="train.clean.100[:10]", trust_remote_code=True)

Here i only want to download the first 10 rows but the full train set is being downloaded. how to fix?
